# Silently updating an app on boot and then launching it

Tags: android

I am working on a solution to provide about 200 android tablet devices that need to boot an app at startup. The only function of these tablets is to run said app. I have the boot at startup figured out, however, I am trying to get the app to update from a URL on boot if a new version is detected. I have no idea how to go about doing this. I have a manifest URL and a static url with the latest app.

Comment: you have to use a stub app that has app launch permissions.  The stub app in theory would never need updating but would be capable of updating the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Without root permissions or being on very recent version of android (12+) you will not be able to update an app without user interaction.

If you have a device running Android 12+ you can create your own sort of app store that can install updates without user interaction by using a new [permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#UPDATE_PACKAGES_WITHOUT_USER_ACTION) and using PackageManager to install but the app has to be initially installed by this app to be able to update it.

https://www.xda-developers.com/android-12-alternative-app-stores-update-apps-background/

When you have a device running Android 14+ yo can take ownership of an app when installing so that no other app can install/uninstall it.

https://www.xda-developers.com/android-14-new-apis-app-stores/

Those are your only options